# VS2010 Default Basic Runtime Checks

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

What is the default action in a VS2010 C/C++ Win32 project for the parameter "Basic Runtime Checks = Default".  This can be found in the C/C++ - Code Generation property page.
Thanks in advance.
Max

Answer (score 6):

There are two types of Basic Runtime Checks:

1: Uninitialized variables
2: Corrupted stack frames

Choosing "Default" gives you no runtime checks.
The choices in the dropdown are misleading.